# Advantages of installing from source instead of installer for Python 2.7

Tags: python, installation

I'm a complete beginner learning Python. I noticed the Windows installer for Python states "does not include source" and below it there's an option to install the source via tarball.

http://www.python.org/getit/

What is left out if I install it with the windows installer without the source?

Comment: It just means that you don't have the source code for the Python language. So if you wanted to look at the implementation of a function list `list()` you wouldn't be able to. You can also download the source code separate from the installer if you want it.

Comment: Short answer: as a beginner, use the installer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code.

This can be useful as a reference, or if, for example, you are doing Cython development (where you need the source to compile against).

In general though, the source isn't needed for the average Python user. If you need it, you'll know about it.

Comment: Oh, so it's only used for documentation? I kept thinking it would exclude certain features or functionality if I don't download it.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not only for documentation - there are many other uses, as I said, but for some it can be useful to read the code for the modules they are using. The source is what was compiled/packaged to produce the installer, so it's functionally the same.